# Why is "ни" omitted here to say "nothing"?

Tags: грамматика, значения

> Раз вы не Раиса, то нам **не** о **чем** разговаривать.

```
... then we have nothing to talk about.
```

To convey the idea of "nothing", I usually expect to see the combination of "ни", "не", and "что", as in "**ни** на **что** **не** годится". Why the omission of "ни"?

Or perhaps, is it more related to the 4th [definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5#Russian) of "не"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had it been used with a noun, it would be `разговор ни о чём`, however in this case it's `не`. And again, it should just be memorized. Here are some relevant articles from wiktionary: [ни о чём](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BE_%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC), [не о чем](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

So, `не о чем` indicates that there's nothing to talk about, while `ни о чём` sort indicates that you are talking about nothing [else].

For instance, in this example it will be `ни` as well:

> Будем думать только об экзамене, и больше ни о чём.

Or consider following pair:

> Больше ни о чём я вам не расскажу, ни в чём не признаюсь". (literally - I will tell you about nothing, I will confess nothing).

and

> Не о чем мне вам рассказывать, не в чем мне признаваться". (literally - I have nothing to tell you about, I have nothing to confess).

Comment: Wow, this has turned out to be more complicated than I'd expected!

Comment: @Alone-zee it's not about me, however I want to use this chance as an opportunity to notice - you are not accepting answers. Please, if you find some answer helpful and the most full one - care to mark is as an answer. It's not obligatory, however, it does help other users.

Answer (score 3):

Handling this a little differently: "не" is straightforward "no/not", but "ни" may indeed mean "nothing", like @shabunc rightly says, but also, depending on context, may mean "neither" or "nor" or sort of pointer to "anything" or "whatever".

So, "не то" is "not that [something which was expected/needed/etc.]".

But: "ни то, ни другое" is "neither this, nor that".

And: "чтобы [one word!] не делать" is "[in order] to do not", but "что бы [two words!] ни делать[, лишь бы не работать]" is "to do anything [but work]" or "whatever's one going to do [one's not going to do work]".