# Negative prefixes не- vs. ни-

Tags: отрицание

This is the kind of things I know how to use in practice, but would not manage to explain to someone in theory.

Некогда, нечего, нечем, не с кем... they differ from никогда, ничего, ничем, ни с кем in usage.

- Мне некогда - I have no time (literally "to me no when").
- Нечего делать - There's nothing that can be done.
- Не с кем говорить - There's no one to talk to.
- Нечем дышать! - There's no way to breathe!
- Не о чём жалеть - There's nothing to regret.

But:

- Никогда не будет времени - There will never be [enough] time.
- Ничего не делал - I didn't anything.
- Не говорю ни с кем - I don't talk to anyone.
- Не могу дышать ничем! - I can't breathe in any way!
- Я стараюсь ни о чём не жалеть - I try not to regret anything.

So far so good. In practice, **I know when to use не- and ни-. But how can the difference in usage be explained, say, in a "scientific" way?**

Maybe не- words are used exclusively in impersonal sentences (only with the dative in order to refer to a passive subject, like in "мне некогда"), whereas ни- words are personal, referring to an active subject?

On a side note, which syntax is better?

- Мне не с кем говорить

or

- У меня не с кем говорить

Comment: please make your question clearer

Comment: It's all very easy: **не** is negative, but **ни** is emphatic, look at your examples and notice that **ни** is used only in those sentence that already have **не**. A sentence can have **не** only, but it cannot have **ни** only, **ни** must always be paired with **не**.

Comment: "Не" means logical inversion, denial, negative; but "ни" means "nothing of the kind/alternatives" (and may have other meanings in some contexts https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16799/).

Comment: @shabunc the question or rather the request is pretty clearly stated ***But how can the difference in usage be explained, say, in a "scientific" way?***, and there're already answers showing that people understand it, i vote for reopening

Comment: note also that the ***не-*** words are only used with infinitives, either explicit or implied

Comment: in a rough and crude explanation the ***не-*** words denote absence of an object, the ***ни-*** words denote inadequacy or undesirability of any object available, and in some cases they may denote different objects like in ***нечем*** *(air)* ***дышать*** and ***не дышать ничем*** *(substance or body part)*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I've reopened it and just made the question bold in order to make it immediately visible.

Answer (score 1):

"Не", either in a prefix or as a particle, means logical inversion, denial, negative; but "ни" means "nothing of the kind/none of the variants/alternatives" (and may have other meanings in some contexts: [Why is “ни” omitted here to say “nothing”?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16799)).

Answer (score 1):

As long as all your examples contain pronouns derived from particles and other pronouns we can talk about pronouns only for a while.
In the case Yellow Sky's comment is right. You can treat "не(когда/где/куда/etc)" as negative pronouns, which mean absence of time/place/direction/etc. Whereas "ни(когда/где/куда)" stresses the negation expressed by "не + verb" construction. The negative construction can be omitted, but is usually obvious. E.g. "В комнате никого [нет]" -- Nobody in the room.

I think it's worth to mention "некто" and "нечто". The former is for 'someone', the latter -- 'something amazing' or 'something unknown, obscure'. "Некто ничего не делал" - someone (we don't know him/her) didn't anything.
"То, что он сделал, -- это нечто!" - he made something wonderful.

And be careful! We like to play with "ни".
E.g. sometimes they describe their idleness as "Делаю ничего". Don't be confused: that still means "ничего не делаю", with some connotation perhaps.
On the other hand, "Ты никто/ничто" is indignity.

These particles are also used separately from pronouns. 
Main logic is the same. "Не" means negation, "Ни" - emphasis of negation.

Also "ни..., ни..." сonstruction is used like English "neither... nor...". 

"В прошлом году ни Италия, ни Франция не прошли в четвертьфинал." -- 'Neither Italy nor France got to the quarter finals last year.'